# How to display only years from given range(2010 to 2020) in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using following code to display only the years:

```
$(".date_year").datetimepicker({
        autoclose: true,
    format: " yyyy",
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years",
    });
```

But I need the starting (2010) and ending (2020) range to display the years.

Answer (score 0):

The startDate and endDate options allows you to restrict the selection, try the below code

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: " yyyy",
        viewMode: "years",
        minViewMode: "years",
        startDate:"2010",
        endDate:"2020"
});
```

Update:
If you want to show only the years between 'startDate' and 'endDate' then add the below css

```
span.year.disabled
{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: @venky07 What is that you are looking for? Do want to restrict the users to select only years between x and y? or you expect the control to show only the years that is between x and y?

Comment: @venky07, did you try the css hack that I mentioned in the update?

Comment: I tried with that css. still am not getting the results what i expected.